# Get header row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the foll. text file:

```
line_1
line_2
line_3
Col_A    Col_B   Col_C
1.2      33       45
23       12       55
```

Here is how I read it:

```
df  = pandas.read_table(file_name, skiprows=3, sep=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
```

Is there any way I can access just the header row?i.e. `'Col_A    Col_B   Col_C'` as a string? I do not want to use `df.columns.values` since it returns an array. I want to get the header row with the spacing between different columns preserved.

Comment: do you mean `df.columns.str.join(' ')` or `' '.join(df.columns)` if you want a str

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:

```
In [6]:
' '.join(df)

Out[6]:
'Col_A Col_B Col_C'
```

This works because the iterable returned from a df are the columns which are strings so you can just `join` them with your separator.

**EDIT**

If you want to get exactly what your header was stored then you can do the following:

```
In [8]:
df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(t), skiprows=3, header=None, nrows=1)
df

Out[8]:
                        0
0  Col_A    Col_B   Col_C

In [10]:
df.iloc[0][0]

Out[10]:
'Col_A    Col_B   Col_C'
```

So this doesn't specify a separator so it will look for commas which there are none so the entire header row is read as a single column value, you can then get just the row value by indexing it as shown above

Comment: sorry, I should have been clearer. I want to preserve the number of spaces between Col_A, Col_B and Col_C. Using ' '.join does not preserve that

Comment: @user308827 When you add the header rows to a dataframe, are the sapces preserved in each coloum? What is the delimeter of the dataframe?? Is it delimeted by spaces?

Comment: Since you read your csv in and specified the separator then you lose the original spaces you could do it using this: `df = pandas.read_table(file_name, skiprows=3, header=None, nrows=1)` this wlll create a single row df with just your header as the data row, you can then just do `df.iloc[0][0]` to get the header as a string

Comment: @pelumi, the delimiter is spaces. Not sure if spaces are preserved though

Comment: Yes you can ignore that bit, it's just for me to load your data